# Is GLEW accurate enough to handle OpengGL extensions ?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glew

I recently experienced some issues with `GLEW` and `OpenGL` extension `GL_direct_state_access`.

Although a call to `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` indicated  that `GL_EXT_direct_state_access` was available, after calling `glewInit()` with a properly nitialized context, the variable `GLEW_EXT_direct_state_access` remains equal to `GL_FALSE`.

I posted some questions and finally downloaded `GLEW` source-code to figure out what's really happening.
So I realized that among all the functions part of `GL_EXT_direct_state_access` group, only 4 are unavailables on my Laptop (OpenGL 3.3 core profile):

```
glVertexArrayVertexAttribDivisorEXT
glVertexArrayVertexAttribIOffsetEXT
glVertexArrayVertexAttribOffsetEXT
glVertexArrayVertexOffsetEXT
```

But all the others func pointers are availables, especially the few that I need:
`glTextureParameterxxxEXT`

Basically, `glewInit()` succeeded, `GLEW_EXT_direct_state_access` equals FALSE, but most of the function pointers are valid (except the four above).

Whether it's a bug or not, I just wonder if I can rely on `GLEW` variables to implement the necessary workaround in my program.

Wouldn't it be better in a program, to simply check the `GL_EXT_direct_state_access` and manually try to get the  function pointers effectively needed ?

Comment: in that case you would not need GLEW at all. but when you realize how many extensions and functions you are talking about you would need to write your own GLEW like stuff ... which is too much work for nothing (that is at least my opinion). And to answer your question you are most likely using Intel gfx so in 99% is this not GLEW issue but the driver side issue. I get it a lot. the only drivers that are made correctly are from nVidia (mostly). AMD is trying matching too (ATI was unable to write decent GL driver for decades but after the takeover things got better for a while)

Comment: GLEW probably queried the extension string, tried to load all the functions but because of the handful of functions not exposed, came to the conclusion that the extension was not implemented. This is actually the first I am hearing of any Intel drivers implementing `GL_EXT_direct_state_access`, it used to be AMD/NV were the only vendors who had drivers that supported it. Now Intel claims to have one, but hasn't fully implemented it...